# Generic interface matching with dummy arguments which contain unlimitted polymorphic pointers

Tags: pointers, generics, interface, fortran, intel-fortran

I came across a weird thing when I used Fortran unlimited polymorphic pointers as dummy arguments. The code is as follows:

```
module TestValueOperation
  implicit none
  type TValue
    class(*),pointer :: Value => NULL()
  end type TValue

  interface ValueOperation
    module procedure :: ValueOperation1
  end interface ValueOperation

  contains
    subroutine ValueOperation1(Val)
      class(*),pointer :: Val
      write(*,*) "This is a test."
    end subroutine ValueOperation1
end module TestValueOperation

program main
  use TestValueOperation
  implicit none
  type(TValue) :: a
  call ValueOperation1(a%Value)  ! Case 1, valid
  call ValueOperation(a%Value)   ! Case 2, invalid
end program main
```

The compiler just complains that

> "There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine
>   call"

with case 1 but works well with case 2.
Could anyone tell me why? The compiler is `ifort 2013_sp1.3.174` if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a (known) compiler bug of `ifort` related to procedures with that have dummy arguments with unlimited polymorphism, see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/537784).

---

`gfortran` accepts and runs the code in all versions I tested.

With `ifort` I (successfully) tested versions 2012 and 2013. I don't have the 2014 version available, but the latest version (2015) fails with the message you got.